# Как в Inno Setup установить ярлык на рабочий стол после включении галочки в дополнительном ПО?

Tags: windows, inno-setup

Мне нужно чтоб в окне инсталятора при установке на компьютер, в параметрах дополнительное ПО, отображался пункт установить сервер, и если пользователь поставить галочку (что б установился сервер, то это отобразилось ярлыком запуска на рабочем столе.
А если не поставит галочку то установилась только иконка самой основной игры на рабочем столе.
Мне кажется что это функция расположена в `[Task]`
Так как после добавлении этой строчки:

```
Name: "desktopicon"; Description: "Установить сервер"; GroupDescription: "{cm:AdditionalIcons}"; Flags: unchecked
```

Появилось дополнительное меню как мне и нужно, но как связать её с `[Icon]`
Если пользователь НЕ поставит галочку, мне нужно чтоб иконка сервера НЕ отображалась на рабочем столе, если поставит то чтоб отображалась и запускала exe-файл который будет вложен как дополнительные файлы в *inno setup*

Мой теперешний код:

```
[Languages]
Name: "english"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Default.isl"

[Tasks]
Name: "desktopicon"; Description: "{cm:CreateDesktopIcon}"; GroupDescription: "{cm:AdditionalIcons}"; Flags: unchecked
Name: "desktopicon"; Description: "Установить сервер"; GroupDescription: "{cm:AdditionalIcons}"; Flags: unchecked

[Files]
Source: "D:\Inno Setup 5.5.5 Rus Portable\Inno Setup 5.5.5 Rus Portable\Examples\MyProg.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion

[Icons]
Name: "{group}\Моя программа"; Filename: "{app}\MyProg.exe"
Name: "{commondesktop}\Моя программа"; Filename: "{app}\MyProg.exe"; Tasks: desktopicon

Name: "{group}\Запустить сервер"; Filename: "{app}\MyProg.exe"
Name: "{commondesktop}\Запустить сервер"; Filename: "{app}\MyProg.exe"; Tasks: desktopicon
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Мне представляется, что флажок установки сервера следует перенести на стадию `[Components]`, а стадию `[Tasks]` пропускать в методе `CurStepChanged` если установка сервере не была выбрана. А вообще шаг со значком на рабочем столе можно смело выкидывать.

Comment: спасибо, целую)